# How do I move my family to Windhelm?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So I'm playing Skyrim, and I have a family in Whiterun. (Wife, and 2 children) I have a lot of items there. And I just bought a house in Windhelm. I tried to see if they would move. But there's no option.

Comment: See if what would move? The family or the items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your family to move, you will need to accommodate them in the new abode - A bed for your partner, (wife/husband) and a bed for each child. Speak to the Steward of the Hold (for WindHelm, this is [Jorleif](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Jorleif)) for this new house, and they should give you the options to add these to the new house.

If you want to move your items, you're going to have to manually transport them. An exploit you can use for this is the [Dead Thrall](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Thrall) spell. You will need to murder someone (a companion perhaps, or your old House Carl), then load all of your items into their corpse. Next, resurrect them with the Dead Thrall spell, travel to your new house, where you can then promptly murder them again, and unload your items. Who said luggage wasn't portable?

Comment: That's an awful and very convenient way to carry items :P.

Comment: "Get the luggage! We're moving again!" *[Drags corpse out of the closet]*